# Probability of a random selection of $2$ out of $5$ shoes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> From a set of five pairs of shoes, two of the shoes are selected at random. Find the probability of each of the following:
>
> a) Both are from the same pair.

My answer: $\dfrac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}$

> b) One left shoe and one right shoe are selected.

My answer: $\dfrac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}$

Note: Solve this problem by counting combinations (i.e $\binom{n}{k}$).

Can someone check if this is correct? If not, can you explain why it is incorrect?

Comment: Ohh! How did you highlight my questions?

Comment: You can simply use `>` at the beginning of the paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numerators in your solutions are incorrect. Considering the two different questions:

1. Both shoes must be from the same pair. Using probability on the first and second draw, we find: $$\frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9} = \frac{1}{9}$$ With your suggested approach, however, we find: $$\frac{10 \cdot 1}{45} = \frac{2}{9}$$ In the numerator, we must only mention the combinations of shoes we pick, not multiply the values for the two different draws. Instead, try writing it as follows: $$\frac{5 \choose 1}{10 \choose 2} = \frac{5}{45} = \frac{1}{9}$$ There are five pairs we can draw, and 45 possible pairs of draws.
2. Similarly as for (a), the numerator is incorrect. Using probability on the first and second draw, we find: $$\frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{9} = \frac{5}{9}$$ Using combinations, you should arrive at the following: $$\frac{{5 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}}{10 \choose 2} = \frac{25}{45} = \frac{5}{9}$$ In this way, we consider all pairs of draws in which one shoe is drawn from the left shoes and one shoe is drawn from the right shoes.

Comment: Another nice answer.  A little help with the English terminology:  The number above the fraction bar is called the numerator.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I really should consider hiring you as my personal interpreter. Corrected!

Comment: Thank you @jvdhooft for the help and explanation. You are helping me and countless others!